# Issues with running trading strategies on European stocks using zipline

Tags: python, zipline

I am encountering problems with running strategies based on European stocks using zipline. I have also raised the issue on Github, but so far I have not heard back about it.

Steps:

1. I downloaded data into CSV files (two files names abn.csv and aex.csv). The head of one looks like this:

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume,dividend,split
2017-01-02,21.100000381469727,21.295000076293945,20.94499969482422,21.274999618530273,407919,0,0
2017-01-03,21.334999084472656,22.06999969482422,21.334999084472656,21.950000762939453,1453872,0,0
2017-01-04,21.989999771118164,22.135000228881836,21.934999465942383,22.125,1169976,0,0
```

2. I modified the `extension.py` file to contain:

```
import pandas as pd

from zipline.data.bundles import register
from zipline.data.bundles.csvdir import csvdir_equities

start_session = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-02', tz='utc')
end_session = pd.Timestamp('2019-06-28', tz='utc')

# register the bundle
register(
    'eu_stocks',  
    csvdir_equities(
        ['daily'],
        '/path/',
    ),
    calendar_name='XAMS',  # Euronext Amsterdam
    start_session=start_session,
    end_session=end_session
)
```

3. I ingested the data
4. I ran the following strategy

```
def initialize(context):
    set_benchmark('aex')
    context.asset = symbol('abn')

def handle_data(context, data):
    order_target_percent(context.asset, 0.5)
```

What results in the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1483315200000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9eaf08e4c73f> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('zipline', '--start 2017-1-2 --end 2019-6-28 --capital-base 1050.0 --bundle eu_stocks -o out.pkl', "\ndef initialize(context):\n    set_benchmark('aex')\n    context.asset = symbol('abn')\n\ndef handle_data(context, data):\n    order_target_percent(context.asset, 0.5)")

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2165             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2166             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2167                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2168             return result
   2169 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__main__.py in zipline_magic(line, cell)
    309             '%s%%zipline' % ((cell or '') and '%'),
    310             # don't use system exit and propogate errors to the caller
--> 311             standalone_mode=False,
    312         )
    313     except SystemExit as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in main(self, args, prog_name, complete_var, standalone_mode, **extra)
    695             try:
    696                 with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
--> 697                     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
    698                     if not standalone_mode:
    699                         return rv

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in invoke(self, ctx)
    893         """
    894         if self.callback is not None:
--> 895             return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
    896 
    897 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py in invoke(*args, **kwargs)
    533         with augment_usage_errors(self):
    534             with ctx:
--> 535                 return callback(*args, **kwargs)
    536 
    537     def forward(*args, **kwargs):

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/decorators.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     15     """
     16     def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
---> 17         return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
     18     return update_wrapper(new_func, f)
     19 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/__main__.py in run(ctx, algofile, algotext, define, data_frequency, capital_base, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, blotter)
    274         local_namespace=local_namespace,
    275         environ=os.environ,
--> 276         blotter=blotter,
    277     )
    278 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/utils/run_algo.py in _run(handle_data, initialize, before_trading_start, analyze, algofile, algotext, defines, data_frequency, capital_base, data, bundle, bundle_timestamp, start, end, output, trading_calendar, print_algo, metrics_set, local_namespace, environ, blotter)
    167             equity_minute_reader=bundle_data.equity_minute_bar_reader,
    168             equity_daily_reader=bundle_data.equity_daily_bar_reader,
--> 169             adjustment_reader=bundle_data.adjustment_reader,
    170         )
    171 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zipline/data/data_portal.py in __init__(self, asset_finder, trading_calendar, first_trading_day, equity_daily_reader, equity_minute_reader, future_daily_reader, future_minute_reader, adjustment_reader, last_available_session, last_available_minute, minute_history_prefetch_length, daily_history_prefetch_length)
    289                 self._first_trading_day
    290             )
--> 291             if self._first_trading_day is not None else (None, None)
    292         )
    293 

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/trading_calendars/trading_calendar.py in open_and_close_for_session(self, session_label)
    758         # http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#datetime-with-tz  # noqa
    759         return (
--> 760             sched.at[session_label, 'market_open'].tz_localize(UTC),
    761             sched.at[session_label, 'market_close'].tz_localize(UTC),
    762         )

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1867 
   1868         key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 1869         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   1870 
   1871     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

~/anaconda3/envs/env_zipline2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   1983 
   1984         try:
-> 1985             return engine.get_value(series._values, index)
   1986         except (TypeError, ValueError):
   1987 

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```